# How to disable canvas elements from hijacking mouse wheel when scrolling through a page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

In HTML5 (I think?), Canvas elements on the page will interrupt scrolling when the mouse is hovering over them.

I have generated a page using Chart.js, which has many graphs on it, all of which are rendered inside a  element.

Since the page is very long (vertically), the user will often scroll up / down the page to look at the various graphs. Each time they scroll onto a , they have to mouse out to continue scrolling, which is inconvenient.

Is there any way to override the canvas element's control of the mouse wheel event? I have no functionality tied to the mouse wheel. In the interim I've advised users to use keyboard shortcuts.

Thanks, as always, to this incredibly helpful community. If I find a work-around or solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just using [Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs), I don't think Chart.js will hijack the wheel event. But if you use [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom) together, the wheel event will be hijacked.

(chartjs-plugin-zoom is a zoom and pan plugin for Chart.js)

chartjs-plugin-zoom hijacks mouse wheel when scrolling. If you would like the user to use mouse wheel to scroll up or down the page, instead of zooming in or out a chart, you can un-register the wheel event from the chart, as below:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
myChart.ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('wheel', myChart._wheelHandler);
```

You can re-add the event handler whenever needed:

```
myChart.ctx.canvas.addEventListener('wheel', myChart._wheelHandler);
```

Check out [this example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyougo/sv2n4zdh/2/).

Answer (score 2):

This is an example canvas:

```css
canvas
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Run the snippet and test it. You will see there is no scroll suppression at all.

What you experience is something Chart.js adds on purpose.

To remove it do, with jQuery, as follows:

```
$(function () {
  $("*").off("scroll");
});
```

This will remove all scroll handlers from all elements on the page, or a less aggressive way:

```
  $("canvas").off("scroll");
```

This last way is less aggressive and keeps non-canvases alone, but it may not suffice. The scroll handler may be attached to an ancestor of the canvas, such as a an invisible div.

Answer (score 2):

To exclusively capture the event you could directly change the `onmousewheel` method of the element.

```
this.canvas.onmousewheel = function(evt){
    //perform your own Event dispatching here
    return false;
};
```

```

Answer (score 1):

Config option in setup. This will disable the zoom plugin.

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    zoom: false
  }
}
```